# How to give dark background to div than the original background?

Tags: html, css

I am making calendar view for my php website.
I have one table with n rows. and in that table odd rows have light green background and even have light pink background.

and after that i have some div which are place on the corresponding tr with z-index: 8 css property.

But i want to give them dark background than their background table row.

Like divs which comes over pink row should have dark pink background and green row divs should have dark green background.

both the table and div are being developed automatically by jquery code.

can anyone help me in this that how can i achieve this ?

I am doing it in jquery fullcalendar resource view .

My some html and css code is :

```
css :

.fc-border-separate tr th{
background: #BFDBFF;
}
.fc-border-separate tr:nth-child(odd) td{
background: #D7FFD7; 
}
.fc-border-separate tr:nth-child(even) td{
background: #FFD5FF;
}
.fc-event {
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0;
font-size: .85em;
cursor: default;
}

 a.fc-event,
 .fc-event-draggable {
cursor: pointer;
}

a.fc-event {
text-decoration: none;
}

.fc-rtl .fc-event {
text-align: right;
}

.fc-event-skin {
border-color: #36c;     /* default BORDER color */
background-color: #36c; /* default BACKGROUND color */
color: #fff;            /* default TEXT color */
}

.fc-event-inner {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

html :

```
 <table class="fc-border-separate tblcalendar">
 </table>

 <div class='fc-event fc-event-skin fc-event-inner' style='position: absolute; z-index:8'>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you show us some of the css/html you have so far to get us started. I could take guesses at your class names, but we could give you the exact solution.

Comment: ya i can give you my css class name and html which i tried. wait m posting it

Comment: This is what i am exactly doing : http://tux.fi/~jarnok/fullcalendar-resourceviews/  i managed to give alternative color to the calendar rows. but now i want to give events the relative colors like dark green and dark pink

Comment: Do you want to be able to pick the color specifically depending on the row or do you just want to darken the color in the same fashion regardless of the underlying color? In other words, would using, for example, `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2)` on `.fc-event` be satisfactory?

Comment: yes i want to be able to pick the color specifically depending on the row. means if the row color is light green than div color should be dark green like wise.

Comment: Thanks jonesbp. RGB Alpha with opacity works perfectly for me. I tried only opacity : 0.5 before but it didn't work. but rgba(0,0,0,0.2) in .fc-event works fine. Please post that in answer so that i can accept it as answer. and other viewers also.

Answer (score 0):

[Is this what you're looking for?](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/XQzeL/3/)

The basic idea is to use the pseudo-class `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)`, like so:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:lightgreen;
    height:60px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:pink;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) div {
    background-color:green;
}

tr:nth-child(even) div {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: thanks Austin Mullins but i already did this. but i want to give background color to divs which are displaying on table row with z-index but they are not exactly child of that table. I have attached my code here also.